# Is "geth debug trace_2" on "Etherscan.io" a native geth output?

Tags: go-ethereum, etherscan, geth-debugging

I am aware of the `debug_traceTransaction` function.
On Etherscan.io there is an option to view transaction, called `Geth Debug Trace_2`, which produces output in a format that I need. The option is here:

[image]

And the output looks like this

```
    {
    "type": "CALL",
    "from": "0x5c0c754e08d545e219e0dc8c440f934dc12bac7f",
    "to": "0x4fa2cc6ad3f94e0f99111943985c24d7d3f188cf",
    "value": "0x2386f26fc10000",
    "gas": "0x12e48",
    "gasUsed": "0x1e48",
    "input": "0x312e5a61000000000000000000000000fe89009eda90321fd48f9c6b97bcf4e86a79f71c",
    "output": "0x",
    "time": "3.0075ms",
    "calls": [
        {
        "type": "CALL",
        "from": "0x4fa2cc6ad3f94e0f99111943985c24d7d3f188cf",
        "to": "0xfe89009eda90321fd48f9c6b97bcf4e86a79f71c",
        "value": "0x2386f26fc10000",
        "input": "0x"
        }
    ]
    }
```

My question is: can I obtain data from geth in a same format or does Etherscan calculate that data based on `debug_traceTransaction` ?

Answer (score 3):

I found it.

According to https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16408
I had to pass `{"tracer":"callTracer"}` to `debug_traceTransaction`

Comment: hi, are you still using this trace today? or did you find something else?

Comment: hi, sorry but I am longer working at the company I needed this for